# Material Design RecyclerView Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, material-design

How do I archive a layout for my RecyclerView that looks like this:
[image]

I have tried creating it but it did ever look like in the giudlines.

This is taken form the Material Design Guidlines, but I could not find any xml Layouts, except Sketch and or PSDs.
Are there any ressources directl in xml?

**Edit 1:** I only need the **single list item XML layout**

**Edit 2:** I know how to use & implement a RecyclerView

Comment: You need to make `XML Layout` on your own. Go and Try it.

Comment: You want to create a header list?

Comment: @Funkyidol the header list is not important, I need the single list item layout

Comment: @jaydroider Why does Google not provide them? They have guidelines, but do not offer a solution. This is weird

Answer (score 1):

create a .xml that have what you want inside **example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="17dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gasImagem"
            android:contentDescription="cover"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            /> 
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gasTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gasPreco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCarro"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background = "@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/shoppingcart"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After this create an adapter  **example**

```java
public class MyAdaptadorRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdaptadorRecycler.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Produto>gasList;
    private LayoutInflater layout;


    public MyAdaptadorRecycler(Context c,List<Produto>l){
        gasList = l;
        layout = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = layout.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.ivcapa.setImageResource(gasList.get(position).getImagem());
        holder.tvtitulo.setText(gasList.get(position).getNome());
        holder.tvPreco.setText(String.valueOf(gasList.get(position).getPreco()) + "€");
        final int posicao = position;
        holder.bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Carrinho: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Recycle Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gasList.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView tvtitulo, tvPreco;
        protected ImageView ivcapa;
        protected Button bt;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.tvtitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gasTitulo);
            this.ivcapa = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gasImagem);
            this.tvPreco = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gasPreco);
            this.bt = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btCarro);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you will need a divider  **exemple:**

```java
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mVerticalSpaceHeight;

    public DividerItemDecoration(int mVerticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.mVerticalSpaceHeight = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.bottom = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
        //outRect.left = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
        //outRect.right = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }
}
```

Then in your mainActivity you **need to do this:**

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
this.rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(20));
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
nr= 1;
this.listaPordutos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
this.adapatadorLivros = new MyAdaptadorRecycler(this, listaPordutos);
rv.setAdapter(this.adapatadorLivros);
```

**This is just my exemples, that I use to create a program**

hope this can help you, any doubt just say :)

Answer (score -1):

Refer this official documentation link on how to use RecyclerView.LayoutManager http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to use a RecyclerView, but I need the xml layout shown in the guidlines